# JMeter: bzm Random Csv Data Set Config is showing blank result in test csv section

Tags: jmeter

I have a csv file with test data and need using Random CSV Data Set Config to read the data in random order.
When click on Test CSV Reading I got the records. The strange thing is that I have records with data and some with blank data. What is the reason for records with empty data? Is there is any setup that I was missing? Thanks in advance for the help

I checked the csv for empty cells, but everything looks ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check it using "normal" [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) as I cannot reproduce your issue

[image]

eventually check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries and use [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) to inspect what JMeter Variables are set and see their values using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener.

---

If you think that this is a bug in the plugin you can reach out to the plugin developers and/or maintainers via [JMeter Plugins Support Forum](https://groups.google.com/g/jmeter-plugins)

as a workaround you can randomize your existing CSV file using:

1. [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter)
2. [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with the following code:

   ```
   File csv = new File('/path/to/your/csv/file.csv')

   def original = csv.readLines()

   Collections.shuffle(original)

   csv.withWriter { out ->
       original.each { out.println(it) }
   }
   ```

   this way all the lines will be "shuffled" each time you run your test and you will be able to use "normal" CSV Data Set Config.